# Template in which one argument depends on another argument

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following situation. Let say we want to implement a sorted array data structure which keeps the array sorted upon insertion. At first attempt, I would do something like:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename Comparator, Comparator comparator>
SortedArray {
public:
    void find(T value);
    void insert(T value);
    void remove(T value);
}
```

The argument `T` is of course for the type of the elements in the array. Then I need a comparator to tell how to compare objects of type `T` so that I can keep the elements sorted. Since I want to allow for both function pointers (as in classical `qsort`) as well as function objects and maybe lambda as well, I need to add the template parameter for the comparator.

Now the problem is that I want the compiler to **automatically deduce the 2nd `Comparator` argument based on the 3rd argument**. Right now, a typical usage will be exploiting `decltype` like

```cpp
int compare_int(int x, int y) {
    return x - y;
}
SortedArray<int, decltype(compare_int), compare_int> myArray;
```

but this doesn't work with lambda and certainly I would love to just write

```cpp
SortedArray<int, compare_int> myArray;
```

instead.

Any idea or is it actually possible in C++ at the moment?

Comment: You likely don't want to pass `comparator` as a non-type template parameter - if nothing else, that precludes a comparator of class type, you are limiting yourself to plan function pointers. Why don't you do what `std::set` does - it has the same requirements (it needs a comparator to keep its elements sorted). Namely, the type of the comparator is passed as a template parameter, the comparator itself can be passed in the constructor; if not, the default-constructed instance is used.

Comment: As of C++17, you can write `template<typename T, auto comparator> SortedArray {...};` Here `comparator` is a non-type template parameter whose type is deduced from the corresponding template argument during instantiation. This would let you write `SortedArray<int, compare_int> myArray;` when `compare_int` is a function (but not when it's a lambda - again, non-type template parameters can't be of class type).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I think an answer would be a better medium to explain all this

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That is precisely what I wanted. I want to do it this way so that compare function is determined and possibly **inlined at compile time**. Keeping the comparator as a class member will not allow that, I think; unless there is some mechanism I am not aware of.

Comment: If you have `class Comp { bool compare(int a, int b); }` and `class DataStructure { Comp comp; void f() {comp.compare(1, 2);} };` I don't see any reason why the compiler cannot inline `compare` into `f` if it has its body available, just because `comp` is a data member of `DataStructure`.

Comment: @AnHoa A compiler could likely inline the comparator stored as a member if the container's constructor was evaluated in the same function for from another inline-able function. If you're okay with only allowing function pointers as the comparator, probably `template<typename T, auto comp>` is the way. If it would be worth the complication, some partial specializations and helpers could have the class use a comparator member when necessary, or no comparator member when possible.

Comment: @Igor It gets harder (still sometimes possible) if the analogy is `class DataStructure { bool (*comp)(int, int); public: DataStructure(bool (*fp)(int,int)) : comp(fp) {} void f() { comp(1, 2); } };`

Comment: @aschepler Well, a more precise analogy would be `template <bool (*comp)(int, int)> class DataStructure {...};` But in any case, we seem to be in agreement that having a comparator of class type as a data member is more likely to permit inlining than a function pointer, whether stored as a data member or passed as a template parameter.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik @aschepler I see. I think the other issue was space consumption (e.g. when using `SortedArray` to implement a search tree). I thought`sizeof(Comp)` should be 0 for class without any member field (i.e. method-only) but turns out it is 1 byte.

Comment: `sizeof(T) > 0` for any complete type `T`. One possible trick is to privately derive from `Comparator` rather than having it as a member, in hopes of taking advantage of [empty base optimization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik So empty base optimization works for class empty-class Comparator, but passing a function pointer such as `compare_int` in constructor (and stored as member field of `DataStructure`) still incurs 4-8 bytes (sizeof function pointers), am I right?

Comment: In C++20 you can just use `[[no_unique_address]]` instead of empty base optimization tricks.

Comment: Yes, of course the data member of function pointer type would occupy space equal to the size of that type; which indeed would be 4 or 8 on a typical implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can non type template parameters as follows:

```
template<typename T, auto C > 
class SortedArray 
{
    private:
    std::vector<T> v;
    public:
    void sort(){ std::sort( v.begin(), v.end(), C );} 
    void print() { for( auto& el: v ) std::cout << el << std::endl; }
    void push(T t){ v.push_back(t);}
};

bool compare_int( int a, int b ) 
{
    return a<b;
}

int main()
{
    SortedArray<int, compare_int> sa1;
    sa1.push(5);
    sa1.push(3);
    sa1.push(7);

    sa1.sort();
    sa1.print();


    SortedArray<int, [](int a, int b){ return a<b;} > sa2;
    sa2.push(5);
    sa2.push(3);
    sa2.push(7);

    sa2.sort();
    sa2.print();
}
```

As you can see, you can also use a lambda as template parameter.

There is no need to do any template gymnastic with derived template parameters anymore.

Comment: "you can also use a lambda as template parameter" [No you cannot](https://godbolt.org/z/fGTf1K)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: C++20 allows lambdas as non type template parameter in the same way as other user defined types can be a non type template parameter. That clang did currently not support it and you use C++17, did not mean that C++20 did not allow it. Code compiles fine with gcc10 and did what we expect.